# Large Dataset query fails if column contains Missing

Tags: bugs, dataset, query

In version 11.0 (Win 8.1 Pro) a query on a large `Dataset` for a column that contains `Missing` fails most unceremoniously.

With

```
dsTest = AssociationThread[{"a", "b"}, 
     If[Last@# == 10000, {Missing["No Data"], Last@#}, #]] & /@ 
   Transpose@{RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 22000], Range[22000]} // 
  Dataset;
```

One row has column `"a"` set to `Missing["No Data"]`.  Then

```
dsTest[All, "a"]
```

[image]

Bug, yes?

**Work-around**

A work-around is to remove the `Missing` instances from the `Select`.

```
dsTest[Select[Head[#"a"] =!= Missing &], "a"]
```

More work-arounds in comments/answers below.

**Confirmed Bug** - [CASE:3720717]

Comment: I reported it as a bug

Answer (score 8):

Extended comment converted to a non-answer, nailing down what is required to trigger this bug:

Here's a simple `Dataset` with one key having all string values, another having integer values:

```
ds = Association @@@ ({"a" -> ToString@#, "b" -> #} & /@ Range[20]) // 
  ReplacePart[{1, 1} -> Missing[]] // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we query the integer values, then we see that the displayed form changes based on whether the number of rows we ask for is less than 9,

```
{ds[;; 8, "b"], ds[;; 9, "b"], ds[All, "b"]}
```

[image]

It switches from a column view to a grid-view when you query more than 8 elements.  This is also where you have a problem with the "a" column, the `Key` with `String` values,

```
{ds[;; 8, "a"], ds[;; 9, "a"]}
```

[image]

A workaround is to set a global preference to use the old `Dataset` formatting,

```
Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting = False;
{ds[;; 8, "a"], ds[;; 9, "a"]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good work-around (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment: Another example narrowed down to a curious threshold:

```
vars = {"Var_A", "Var_B", "Var_C"};
assoc = AssociationMap[Random[] &] /@ Array[vars[[#2]] &, {9999, 3}];
assoc2 = Prepend[<|"Var_A" -> Random[], "Var_B" -> Random[], "Var_C" -> Missing[]|>]@assoc;
Predict[assoc -> "Var_C"]
Predict[assoc2 -> "Var_C"]
```

works fine but now change 9999 to 10 000 and 
`Predict` fails on `assoc2` apparently confused by the `Missing[]` in the predicted variable.

(Confirmed as a bug a few weeks back)